# For $C$ an ideal of $B$, $\frac{A}{f^{-1}(C)}$ can be embedded in $\frac{B}{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism between commutative rings, and let $C$ be an ideal of $B$.

Then $\frac{A}{f^{-1}(C)}$ is isomorphic to some subring of $\frac{B}{C}$.

My attempt at a proof:

First, notice that $\frac { f^{-1} ( C)}{ker f} \simeq C \cap Im f$ - one way to see this is, is first seeing that $f f^{-1}(C) = C \cap Im f$.

Now, using the isomorphism theorems:

$\frac{A}{f^{-1}(C)} \simeq \frac{ \frac{A}{ker f} }{\frac {f^{-1}(C)}{ker f}} \simeq \frac{Im f}{C \cap Im f} \simeq \frac{Im f + C}{C} \leq \frac{B}{C}$

Is my proof correct? I feel like I might be missing something - is there some neater or more general method of proving things like these, or seeing that they are true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but there's a simpler way.

Consider the composition of $f$ with the canonical projection $\pi:B \to B/C$.
It's easy to see that the kernel of $\pi \circ f$ is precisely $f^{-1}(C)$, by the first isomorphism theorem, we get $A / f^{-1}(C) = A/\ker(\pi \circ f) \cong \operatorname{Im}(\pi \circ f) \leq B/C $.

In general, it can be useful to look at compositions with "naturally" given homomorphism, i.e. inclusions of substructures or projections onto quotient structures.